# Splitting a hunk with magit

Tags: emacs, magit

I have 2 edits very close by (and therefore part of the same hunk), that I'd like to commit separately. Is it possible to split a hunk from within magit?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can set the mark correctly with <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> (C-SPC) and magit will only commit the selected portion.

Comment: I always set the mark at the bottom of the region, and move point to the top in order to stage or unstage regions, as I've had issues (which I can't recall the specifics of) doing it the other way around in the past. YMMV.

Comment: Re: my previous comment, I recently read the reason for this, which is that when you un/stage the region, point must be *within* the region you are acting on. You can, of course, use `C-x C-x` to exchange point and mark if you had done it the other way around.

Comment: Does it behave differently when using transient-mark-mode? Because I always select top to bottom and never had a problem.

Comment: It wasn't enough for me to set the mark (`C-SPC`). I had to press `C-SPC` a second time to activate `transient-mark-mode`.

Comment: to be clear: magit will only commit whatever is selected. It doesn't matter *how* did you select e.g., I use `Shift + <arrows>` to select portion of a hunk and press `s` to stage the selected part.

Answer (score 62):

You can also use <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> to decrease or increase the extent of the hunks in the diff (and <kbd>0</kbd> resets), but dominikh's answer is the most important one to know about.

Comment: This does not work for me, has this been removed in the newer version of magit or is this something peculiar to my setup?

Comment: Mike H-R: assuming you're in the magit-status buffer, then this should still work AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, I was mistaken, you need to press + or - on the line starting `@@` (the hunk information line) rather than inside the hunk as I had been trying to.

Answer (score 0):

Magit reuse `diff-mode` but don't expose many of `diff-mode` commands in its `magit-revision-mode` as this does VC package.

For example you can call `diff-split-hunk` which is usually `C-c C-s` in `diff-mode`.