# Is it possible to split a chunk even further with magit?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting a hunk with magit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521929/splitting-a-hunk-with-magit)

When you review your changes sections you get the chunks as you would when you do for example "git add -p" by default, but I can't find an option to split chunks into smaller chunks as you would by choosing the "s" option when issuing commands with -p, so is it possible?

Comment: You're right my question is a duplicate, didn't find it when I searched. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by phils above this is a duplicate of [Splitting a hunk with magit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521929/splitting-a-hunk-with-magit).

His solution over there worked great for me:

"You can also use <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> to decrease or increase the extent of the hunks in the diff (and <kbd>0</kbd> resets)"

Comment: More specifically, it's `+` and `=`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it manually with "e". It will open your standard editor with the instructions.